# Is there a module for limiting CCK select list options per role?

Tags: entities

I notice we can define a custom php list for options widget in CCK.

Would love to limit allowed values per role?

What would be the easiest way?

Such a solution could replace a lot of other modules, like Workflow etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a module, this is in core.

```
  $values = array(1|one, 2|two, 3|three);

  global $user;

  // Check to see if $user has the administrator role.
  if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    $values[] = 'special|special';
  }
  return $values;
```

[image: limiting allowed values with php]

Comment: Thanks works great! Implemented this for revisioning https://drupal.org/node/1221164